# Hyphens vs. periods in the script slug in wp_register_script?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, customization, wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-script

I have seen script and style handles written in two different ways in `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script` (the same applies to `wp_register_style` and `wp_enqueue_style`):

1. `wp_register_script( 'jquery-someplugin', $location );`
2. `wp_register_script( 'jquery.someplugin', $location );`

#1 uses a hyphen, #2 uses a period. What is the best practice here?

Which should I be using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use hyphens only.

Take a look at `wp-includes/script-loader.php`:

```
$scripts->add( 'scriptaculous-sound', '/wp-in
$scripts->add( 'scriptaculous-controls', '/wp
$scripts->add( 'scriptaculous', '', array('sc

// not used in core, replaced by Jcrop.js
$scripts->add( 'cropper', '/wp-includes/js/cr

$scripts->add( 'jquery', '/wp-includes/js/jqu

// full jQuery UI
$scripts->add( 'jquery-ui-core', '/wp-include
$scripts->add( 'jquery-effects-core', '/wp-in

$scripts->add( 'jquery-effects-blind', '/wp-i
$scripts->add( 'jquery-effects-bounce', '/wp-
$scripts->add( 'jquery-effects-clip', '/wp-in
$scripts->add( 'jquery-effects-drop', '/wp-in
$scripts->add( 'jquery-effects-explode', '/wp
$scripts->add( 'jquery-effects-fade', '/wp-in
$scripts->add( 'jquery-effects-fold', '/wp-in
$scripts->add( 'jquery-effects-highlight', '/
$scripts->add( 'jquery-effects-pulsate', '/wp
$scripts->add( 'jquery-effects-scale', '/wp-i
$scripts->add( 'jquery-effects-shake', '/wp-i
$scripts->add( 'jquery-effects-slide', '/wp-i
$scripts->add( 'jquery-effects-transfer', '/w

$scripts->add( 'jquery-ui-accordion', '/wp-in
$scripts->add( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete', '/wp
```

Yes, I copied a rectangle. :)

The unofficial naming scheme is: main library first, then package, then sub-package, all separated by hyphens.

If you follow this scheme – and other developers too! – you lower the risk to enqueue the same library as another plugin just with another name.

Unfortunately, even in core you can find exceptions: `'suggest'` and `'schedule'` are using jQuery …