# Naming script handles right way

Tags: customization, wp-register-script, wp-register-style

I was wondering is there any convention or what is the right way for naming handles in `wp_register_script()` and `wp_register_style()` functions?

For example if I am developing a plugin that uses modernizer, is it better simply naming it 'modernizer' or something unique like 'my-script-modernizer'?

If it is better to have unique handles and I am developing multiple plugins and I'm sure all uses same script. Should I use same handle in all plugins?

Comment: Related: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58226/hyphens-vs-periods-in-the-script-slug-in-wp-register-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question does to a degree solicit opinionated answers, but I feel it's a good one nonetheless.
As far as *my opinion* goes and the way I handle things is this:

Definitely use the same handle for the same script in all your plugins and/or themes. You don't want to load exact duplicates, if two of your plugins are used in the same WP install.

I give a generic handle to widely used and renowned scripts such as modernizr. Why should such a script be loaded more than once, under different handles?
I prefix handles of my own scripts, for reasons of [namespacing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace).